# Signing Android app with key

Tags: android

folks! I have problems with all that 'signing' stuff. I've followed instructions from developer site and signed my app using Eclipse ADT plugin. I've created keystore, filled information. But I dont't understand following thing: do I need to create separate keystore for every app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You sign all of your apps with the same key.

Answer (score 2):

well... if you ever think there is even a remote possibility of selling any individual apps, you should use a different key for each app and keep them separate.  here is the rationale for this:

http://phandroid.com/2012/06/21/getting-acquired-how-to-transfer-ownership-of-your-android-app-or-game/

Comment: It's been a long time ago, you see;) Almost a year.