# “App_Name” Could not be downloaded due to an error (500)?

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

I Just finished developing a new app. I used my two devices (Galaxy Nexus running 4.02 & Galaxy Tab10.1 running 3.1) to test the app before I published it.

When I published the app to the Market, I removed the tested version of the app (the one Eclipse generated for debugging purpose) from my devices and tried to install the one in the market but I couldn't install it !

In my Nexus device, It gives me this error: *"App_Name" Could not be downloaded due to an error (500).* In my Tab, a progress bar is shown then disappear with no error message.

I thought I had the problem because I tested the app in my devices and the app still cached somewhere on them. Until one of my friends said he has the same error while downloading it using Galaxy S2 running 2.3.3.

FYI, I can install other apps with no problem.

Is this error related to my app? I signed the app with the same key I used to signed another app I published before. Is this a mistake?

Or is it something related to the Market server? My app was added to the market few hours ago. Is it still processing the app

-Thanks

Comment: What is the name of the app in the Market? I'll try to get it and see if gives same error.

Comment: @AlexandruAverescu Thanks. Untiny - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.turkidroid.untiny

Comment: Unfortunately it gives same error: 500. I think you have to sign the app with a new key, one that's not used by other app. That key is used to identify when you are upgrading to a new version, or upload a different app.

Comment: @AlexandruAverescu I did a quick search. What about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8240580/543711) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6166796/543711)? They stated the opposite.

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong on that, in this case it might be a Market problem, one more thing you could try is to remove and add your app again.

Comment: You mean remove it from the dev dashboard?

Comment: If I remember right you have to unpublish it, but you can't remove it completely. That's why I suggested you should sign with a new key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution that solved my problem and others' too:

1. Increment your app's version number and export it again.
2. Re-upload your new .apk file to the market.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the app you uploaded to market from your desktop, not the debugging and testing one. Also I'm guessing you have tried resubmitting the app to market. I uploaded an app the other day and it took a couple of minutes for it to appear on the market but once it was there it was fine to download.

Oh and fyi I got same error on my DHD

Comment: I just tried installing it from my desktop. It is working perfectly! So, does this mean that my app has no problem? and It is a Market issue?

Comment: Seems that way, try uploading it to market again, if not maybe give it a couple hours and try back. I will keep checking my end.

Comment: could check now if you could download it, please?

Answer (score 1):

This is tested and worked. Problem " Unable to download application due to an error. 500".
This happened because of your profile setting sync is off. You should either manually snc your profile account or auto snyc. After you do that, you will be able to download any software from google store - Xplod360

Answer (score 0):

The error code 500 would indicate there is something wrong on the server on which the application is being downloaded from. 'Internal server error' according to the entry on the wikipedia page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: What about if the error was from the APK file I uploaded? Still consider a app-related error, right?